# ActionScript 3 Check Which MovieClip is in a Certain Direction

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

Allright so I am making a little program that allows a user to click a block which then moves into an open space (for simplicity's sake let's assume there is one).

How could I check which MovieClip is to the immediate right/left/bottom/top of the movie clip?

Comment: This will be much easier if you implement some type of 2D grid which stores the position of each MovieClip against a cell - are you intending to implement something similar to that?

Comment: Actually a 2D grid sounds great. Could you perhaps point me to a page that has a good explanation of that?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know any particular articles off the top of my head. That said, it's a pretty basic concept to apply once you give it some thought; you basically just need some type of class that deals with the entire grid and manages which objects fall within which tiles on that grid.

Comment: Make a 2 dimentional vector like so `var MCGrid = new Vector.<Vector.<MovieClip>>(columnNumber);`. Then iterate over the MCGrid items and for each item (column) initialize a new `Vector` of `MovieClip`-s with the number of rows you need. This will give you a grid to work with. It's pretty easy afterwards.

Comment: I actually went ahead and created a grid using a 2D array but now have a different problem. In the program when one clicks the movieclip above a "target" the movieclip and the "target" switch places. This works great except for when I click the one under it I get a "error #1010: a term is undefined and has no properties".